# How to save multiple tables using Spring Boot JpaRepository and their MySQL script

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

//Restaurant entity class

```
public class Restaurant {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Menu> menus;
}
```

//Menu entity class

```
public class Menu {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String type;

    @NotBlank
    private String info;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id")
    private Restaurant restaurant;
}
```

**I have two entities: one is Restaurant and another is menu with end points**

/restaurants

```
GET - get all restaurants
POST - upload restaurant
PUT - Update restaurant
DELETE - delete all restaurant
```

/restaurants/{id}

```
GET - get a restaurant by id
DELETE - delete a restaurant by id
```

/restaurants/{id}/menus/

```
GET - get all menus in the restaurant specified by id
POST - add new menus in the restaurant specified by id
DELETE - delete all menus in the restaurant specified by id
```

Now could you please check weather the entity class are correct and please provide me with the MySQL script to the above entities

Answer (score -1):

You should start with the documentation :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

After that you can see other examples [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/data/spring-data-jparepository-example/) or [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories)

Comment: could you please provide the sql script for the above

Comment: Please read the documentation. If you use Spring Data Jpa Repository, there is no need to write sql scripts. The framework will do it for you